# Can we create table where primary key order does not matter in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have two foreign keys to the same table and don't want to include same keys with different order.

```
CREATE TABLE Interacts_With
( 
    student_1 CHAR(20),
    student_2 CHAR(20),

    PRIMARY KEY (student_1, student_2),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_1) REFERENCES Students(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_2) REFERENCES Students(id)
)
```

I don't want to insert both (1,2) and (2,1).

Is there a way to ensure this in the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Unrelated but: `char(n)` is never a good choice. You should use `varchar()`  instead.

Comment: One way to avoid this in Postgres (or Oracle) is a unique index: `create unique index on interacts_with (least(student_1, student_2), greatest(student_1, student_2));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple method is to ensure that the ids are in order:

```
CREATE TABLE Interacts_With (
    student_1 CHAR(20),
    student_2 CHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY ( student_1  , student_2 ),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_1) REFERENCES Students(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_2) REFERENCES Students(id),
    CHECK (student_1 < student_2)
);
```

Note that you will need to insert the data in the correct order.  Otherwise the insert will fail.

Comment: And it has the neat "side" effect, that a student cannot interact with themselves, which would be possible without the check constraint.